# findElement Error Python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm trying to download a certain link of a webpage but each time i run the code i get an  AttributeError: 'Webdriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'. I'm using selenium and python. here is my code

```
import selenium 
from selenium import web driver

driver = web driver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("The web site I'm trying to take link from")
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("DEV.tgz")
```

Can anybody help me to why I am getting this error

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [`find_element_by_partial_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text) here:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('DEV.tgz')
```

Or, alternatively, you can take [`find_element()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) with `By` approach:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'DEV.tgz')
```